# Select query on multiple databases

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

What I am trying to do is verify a URL. I just need to be able to select that single value from all databases that we have currently in SQL Server 2008. All the databases are the same, just multiple instances of the same database for different users.

I am looking to pull one item from one table in each database.

Each database contains a table `SETTINGS` and within that table a value for `MapIconURL`. I need that value from each table from within each database. I am looking at around 30 or so databases that would have this value.

So I found the "undocumented" Stored Proc sp_MsForEachDb and have working....to a point.
The code I am using is this:

`EXEC sp_MsForEachDb 'use ?; SELECT "?" as databasename,SETTINGSKEYID, SECTION, NAME, INIVALUE, DESCRIPTION
FROM ?.dbo.SETTINGS
WHERE [NAME] = "MapIconURL"'`

I have noticed that it is not selecting all the databases, but that it is also selecting the master table as well as other system tables, and am thinking that may be why it is not selecting all tables.  Is there a way to exclude the system related tables?

Comment: SELECT MapIconURL FROM db1.dbo.SETINGS UNION ALL SELECT MapIconURL FROM db2.dbo.SETINGS ...

Answer (score 0):

If the number (and name) of the databases is fixed, then you could simply do:

```
SELECT MapIconUrl FROM db1.dbo.SETTINGS
UNION ALL
SELECT MapIconUrl FROM db2.dbo.SETTINGS
...
```

However, if either the number or names of the databases is *not* fixed, then you have to build the query dynamically.

First, run a query such as `SELECT name FROM master..sysdatabases` to get the names of the databases.

Then, loop over the result set (in T-SQL, use a [`CURSOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)) and build your query and execute it (in T-SQL, use [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)).